# Which is the event fired after login but with an rebuilded cart

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I have a shopware6 plugin which should store data in the session for certain cart items. Once a user has a dropped session and the user logs in again Shopware6 is rebuilding the cart.
I currently work with CustomerLoginEvent but the cart session not be restored here (yet); so what would be the correct event ?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `SalesChannelContextRestoredEvent`, then get the cart from the restored context's token.

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\ContextRestoredSubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\SalesChannel\CartService"/>

    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
class ContextRestoredSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private CartService $cartService;

    public function __construct(CartService $cartService) 
    {
        $this->cartService = $cartService;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            SalesChannelContextRestoredEvent::class => 'onContextRestored',
        ];
    }

    public function onContextRestored(SalesChannelContextRestoredEvent $event): void
    {
        $context = $event->getRestoredSalesChannelContext();
        $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($context->getToken(), $context);

        // ...
    }
}
```